# Trying to access stackoverflow api but getting parse error

Tags: jquery, stackexchange-api

In trying to use the stackoverflow api with ajax and jquery and I just can't get it to work. I know I have to use `jsonp` as the datatype and I keep reading different ways of doing the jsonp request but I still can't get it to work.

This is my ajax request:

```
var API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
var URL = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/";

var _url = URL + 'users?filter=locrizak';

$.ajax({
    dataType:'jsonp',
    jsonp : false,
    jsonpCallback : "onJsonp",
    url: _url,
    success: function(val) {
            console.log('success');
        //console.log(val);
    },
    error: function(val) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(arguments);

    }
});

function onJsonp() {
    console.log(arguments);
};
```

No matter what I try I always get this response in firebug:

`"parsererror" "onJsonp was not called"`

I know that I am doing something really dumb because I ran into the same issues when trying to use the Twitter api but I can't for the life of me remember what I did to get it to work.

### Update

So I took a loog @genesis's working demo and tried it a few time and different ways but no luck. Then I notice my jQuery version and switched it to the one he was using and it magically worked.

I change the most recent version
`http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js`
to
`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js`

hmm no idea why it works, possibly a bug but who knows maybe something else changed.

If anyone knows why it would be awesome if you could explain. Also I realize that jQuery adds the callback automatically but I could not get it working like that. What could I do to get this working, I guess you would say a "more proper" way?

```
var URL = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/";
api.get(URL + 'users?filter=locrizak');
api.get = function(url) {
    $.ajax({
        /*dataType:'jsonp',*/
        dataType:'json',
        jsonp : false,
        url: url + '&jsonp=api.onJsonp',
        success: function(val) {
            console.log('success');
            //console.log(val);
        },
        error: function(val) {
            //error gets called but.......
            console.log(arguments);
            console.log('error');
            console.log(val);
        }
    });

};
api.onJsonp = function() {
    //so does the callback!!  
    console.log('called');
    console.log(arguments);
}
//note this code is simplified
```

Comment: Poor question title. Can you make it describe the question? Your previous question titles are decent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `jsonp:'jsonp',` to the [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call. The [stackoverflow API documentation](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage) states that it needs the `jsonp` query paramater and the jQuery property to configure the query string parameter passed is called `jsonp`. Without it, the default is to add `callback=?` to the end of the URL.

I get `success` in the console, running this:

```
var URL = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/";
var _url = URL + 'users?filter=locrizak';

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp', // <--- add this
    url: _url,
    success: function(val) {
       console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(val) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(arguments);
    }
});
```

Also, `jsonp:false,` should **not** be set to `false`; it needs to be `true` otherwise no query string parameter is added.

**Update:** Got it working correctly with jQuery v1.6.2 and using the correct parameters as described in my original answer above. The callback function **must be outside** the jQuery anonymous function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>JSONP Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                dataType:'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'onJsonp',
                url: 'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users?filter=locrizak',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('success', data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log('error', data);
                }
            });
        });

        function onJsonp(data) {
            console.log('callback', data);
        };
    </script>
</head><body></body></html>
```

**Update 2:** Based on comments, here is another version, this time wrapped in an object. Note that you cannot use `jsonpCallback: 'api.onJsonp',` because that is only defined inside the jQuery anonymous function. The simplest way to keep the encapsulation is to create a global function and just pass control back to the `api` counterpart.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>JSONP Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            api = {
                get: function(url) {
                    var URL = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/";
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        jsonp: 'jsonp',
                        jsonpCallback: 'onJsonp',
                        url: URL + url,
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log('success', data);
                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                            console.log('error', data);
                        }
                    });
                },
                onJsonp: function(data) {
                    console.log('callback', data);
                }
            }

            api.get('users?filter=locrizak');
        });

        function onJsonp(data) {
            api.onJsonp(data);
        }
    </script>
</head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Only one little problem. I got it to work with a global function. I get success and the `onJsonp` method is called. Once I change `onJsonp` to `api.onJsonp` the callback gets called but the ajax error handler fires.

Comment: as a baidaid solution to this I put `api.onJsonp.apply(api, arguments);` in the global `onJsonp` function but I would really rather call `api.onJsonp` as the request callback and get a successful response.

Comment: @locrizak what you want is impossible I think due to the `api.onJsonp` only existing in the jQuery anonymous closure. I have updated my answer with an improved example that should do what you want.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought just checking if I was missing anything that I should be doing to get it to work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You have to call

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users?filter=locrizak&jsonp=jsonp

[working demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/c1580.php) and code:

```
<script>
var URL = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/";
var api;
api = {
    get: function(url) {
        $.ajax({

            dataType: 'json',
            jsonp: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'api.onJsonp',
            url: url + '&jsonp=api.onJsonp',
        });
    },
    onJsonp: function(val) {
        $("body").prepend(val.users[0].reputation);
        console.log('called');

    }
}

api.get(URL + 'users?filter=locrizak');

//note this code is simplified</script>
```

Comment: sorry i have a couple closures and this is simplified, fixed it now

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: it wasnt before few seconds

Comment: There is a property to configure this on ajax() object. jQuery can automatically add the query string parameter to the end of the URL.

Comment: @genesis. Great! I updated my question but it did cause me to have a couple more.

Answer (score 1):

Is onJsonp defined within a closure? If so, perhaps the fact you're referring to the callback by name ('onJsonp') instead of by reference is the problem?

Two solutions: either define onJsonp in global scope, or pass it by reference by removing the quotes.

Comment: I have tried `api.onJsonp`... api being the closure name as well as a global `onJsonp` method. You cannot pass the function name without the quotes, it needs to be a string because it is added onto the request, not called right away.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    dataType:'jsonp',
    jsonp : true,
    jsonpCallback : "onJsonp",
    url: _url,
    success: function(val) {
            console.log('success');
        //console.log(val);
    },
    error: function(val) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(arguments);

    }
});
```

set jsonp to true.

Comment: That does not work. In the jQuery ajax docs it says to set it to the callback function or false if the callback function will add an extra `?=` and in this case it will